# Unable to upgrade apache poi dependency in jboss server

Tags: java, jboss, apache-poi

I was trying to upgrade apache poi dependency from 3.13 to 5.2.2 in jboss server. I am getting following error. Can someone help on this?

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
10:07:23,359 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 9) ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found
10:07:24,902 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 9) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ContainerManagerEJB for method public void org.kie.server.jms.ContainerManagerEJB.installContainers(org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl,java.util.Set,org.kie.server.services.impl.storage.KieServerState,org.kie.server.controller.api.model.KieServerSetup): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.handleException(BMTInterceptor.java:87) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.checkStatelessDone(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:93) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:89) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
        at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.processSheet(ExcelParser.java:168) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseWorkbook(ExcelParser.java:109) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:83) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.parseResource(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:126) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:110) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:83) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:78) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:44) [drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromResource(DecisionTableFactory.java:37) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.decisionTableToPackageDescr(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:404) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl$12.map(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:441) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildResource(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:326) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackageDescr(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:311) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:115) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:244) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:222) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.build(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:221) [kie-ci-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.buildArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:171) [kie-ci-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:127) [kie-ci-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.loadArtifact(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:122) [kie-ci-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.loadKieModuleFromMavenRepo(KieRepositoryImpl.java:154) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:140) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:117) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:184) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:176) [drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl.createContainer(KieServerImpl.java:244) [kie-server-services-common-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.ContainerManager.installContainersSync(ContainerManager.java:43) [kie-server-services-common-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.ContainerManager.installContainers(ContainerManager.java:33) [kie-server-services-common-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.kie.server.jms.ContainerManagerEJB.installContainers(ContainerManagerEJB.java:38) [kie-server-jms-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_352]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:86) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:97) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: It looks like the current Drools version depends on POI 3.x. Can you try upgrading Drools as well?

Comment: drools-decisiontables 8.31.1.Final depends on POI 5.1.0 - which is probably pretty close to POI 5.2.3 - why use POI 5.2.2 when 5.2.3 is out?

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am using EAP 6.4.0

Comment: It looks like, as @RobSpoor, indicated, there is a mismatch in what Drools expects vs the version of POI you're using. Make sure the version of Drools works with an older container like EAP 6.4.